# Can I see which of my posts/comments have been flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, comments

I am on a personal mission to not be snippy or sarcastic when responding to questions, so I wanted to know if it is possible for me to see flags that have been submitted on my comments and/or answers?

Comment: closely related on uber-meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203216/who-reviews-my-flags-and-suggestions

Comment: I'm not even sure if moderators can see a list of comment flags for a specific user. I will tell you that only three of your regular posts have been flagged, so you don't have a whole lot to worry about. You can do your own audit by going to your profile, then clicking the activity tab and filtering by comments.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. I just was following along in the theme that has been going on MSO for the past several weeks. I got a response to a a comment I wasn't expecting yesterday, so it made me start thinking about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's been an edit on the post I quote here. In fact the implications stay the same, but I thought I'd still tell you ;)

Taken from the MSE post [Who reviews my flags and suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203216/who-reviews-my-flags-and-suggestions) :

> **Notes:**

> When flags go to the review queues where anyone can take action on them, **users are not actually made aware of it being a flag that caused the post to appear there.**

> 10k users **cannot see flags on their own posts** in their tools. However, **moderators can** see flags on their own posts (and comments), but tend to avoid handling them.

Everybody else can't see flags in the first place. They may examine the "results" of flags in the review queue, but the flag itself stays hidden for anyone but moderators.

TL;DR;
No you can't see flags on your own comments or questions

You can, however, find which of your posts have been through the review queues with this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/190371/reviews-on-your-posts).

Comment: This isn't really a good quote, as the flags queue doesn't really matter. 10kers also can't see flags anymore (I updated the mSE post). You might consider quoting something that says you can't see flags on you if you're not a moderator, but I'm not sure what post that would be.

Comment: @hichris123 I edited a little, you're welcome to improve anytime ;)

Comment: I added a Data Explorer query that lets you find reviews of your own posts (I assumed you wouldn't mind because you made it a Community Wiki), which should give you an idea as to what of yours has been flagged (not comments, though). I think it's quite interesting: one of my posts has been used as a (thankfully, positive) audit in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue.

Comment: @AstroCB that's a great link! Thanks for that! I tend to write up a quick code block that solves the problem, then edit and explain in more detail when time permits. Seems I've been generating a lot of Low Quality flags from that (passed them all, however). Interesting to know!

Comment: @AstroCB   I'm trying to use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) link, but its a fail.  I'm seeing `Invalid column name 'my_username'.`  I've tried many variations including email login but no go.  Am I doing this wrong?  Many thx.

Comment: @zipzit Have you tried using your user ID? Go to your main Stack Overlow profile and look at the URL (should be in the form http://stackoverflow.com/users/USERID/USERNAME).

Comment: @AstroCB   Aha!  `http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234567/my_username`  Totally works when I use `1234567` (obviously not my own #) Thx again!